# Change the color of menu items as appBarLayout is being collapsed

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem, android-appbarlayout

To change toolbar background color as appBarLayout is being collapsed
I've used below code

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        float offset = (float) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int) (offset * 255));
    }
});
```

Now I would like to change the color of menu items that is on the toolbar when the appBarLayout is being collapsed like below sample

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quaMk.gif)

Answer (score 0):

```
Menu mItem;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mItem = menu;

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bookmark_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Get the reference of menu.In your offsetchangelistener

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged (AppBarLayout appBarLayout,int verticalOffset){
            float offset = (float) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int) (offset * 255));
            mItem.findViewById(R.id.example).getIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ActivityHome.this, R.color.yourcolor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        });
```

Comment: how this gonna work? you didn't use the offset value. also there is no setColorFilter function for MenuItem object.

Comment: mItem.findViewById(R.id.example).getIcon.setColorFilter is correct.

Comment: It didn't help, not even close. actually just wasted my time. anyway thanks for your answer.